# css footer always bottom of page

Tags: html, css

How do I make the footer always stay bottom of the page (no sticky)? My footer is at the bottom of the screen, but not on the page.

Here is an example of my code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8"/>
     <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="body">Body</div>
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:109px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: i know about it, but i want static footer which is bottom the page and visible when i scroll to the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<style>
  
.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1> 
</div>


<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make the footer appear at the bottom of the container, you need to use position:relative on the container, that way the footer will be at the bottom relative to the container.

Answer (score 2):

With the modern flexbox:
( https://caniuse.com/#search=flex )

```
    html, body, .container {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .header, .footer {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -moz-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    .body {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
        -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using position:relative and bottom:0, you can make your footer at the end of the page

Modify your style-sheet like this and you can clearly understand the effect

```
.footer {
width:100%;
height:109px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background-color: purple;
}
.body {               // I've added this 
    height: 1000px;  // For better understaing
}
```

This footer will visible at the end of the page while scrolling the page